# Shared Element Transition in GridView Weird behavior

Tags: android, gridview, shared-element-transition

I'm using Shared Elements Transition between an imageView in a gridView adapter and an imageView in a details activity , but when i click on an item in the GridView the imageView dosen't start to animate from the right position it always starts under the original place, and when i hit back the image animates to the right place correctly so the glitch happens only when entering the new activity.

https://youtu.be/cprBHWPVNbk (i've slowed down the animation so that the glitch is clear).

**In the BrowseFragment's OnCreate :**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ImageView gridPoster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        gridPoster.setTransitionName("poster" + position);
        listener.onItemSelected(movie,gridPoster);
```

**Then the BrowseActivity's listener starts the detailsActivtiy :**

```
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                    (this, posterView,posterView.getTransitionName());
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, MovieDetalisActivity.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.movie_details_extra_key), movie);
detailsIntent.putExtra("transition",posterView.getTransitionName());
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, detailsIntent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

**Then in the DetailsFragment's OnCreate :**

```
ImageView poster = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.poster);
poster.setTransitionName(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("transition"));
```

**GridViewItem layout :**

```
<LinearLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/gird_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#4e585c"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumb_bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="#aaa"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            />    
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Part of the DetailsView layout :**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:clipChildren="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.rashwan.popularmovies.MovieDetailsActivityFragment"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="310dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:clipChildren="false">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipChildren="false">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:minWidth="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/poster" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ReleaseDate"
                        android:id="@+id/release_date"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="UserRating"
                        android:id="@+id/user_rating"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

And in my Theme i declared         `<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>`i'm not using any custom animation although i tried some and i also tried to postpone the transition but nothing solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem was that i'm using `picasso` library to load the images in the details fragment so i needed to use `postponeEnterTransition();` in the details activity then in the details fragment i use `getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();` to start the transition but only after the image is loaded using `picasso`.

**Here's the code in the details fragment:**

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(posterUri).fit().into(poster, new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess() {
      poster.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
      new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onPreDraw() {
              if (isLollipop) {
                  poster.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                  getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();
              }
              return true;
          }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try putting your classes in manifest.AS

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by putting my classes in manifest.AS?